# Silverlight TextBlock Text Attribute vs Content

Tags: silverlight, textblock

When would I use the Text attribute of the `<TextBlock>` and when should I put my text in the content of the `<TextBlock>`?

```
<TextBlock Text="Example Text" />

            vs.    

<TextBlock>Example Text</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former can be bound, whilst the latter is particularly useful when combining `Run`s:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
<TextBlock>
    <Run>You have </Run>
    <Run Text="{Binding Count}"/>
    <Run>items.</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of the `Text` property has become common as a result of previous versions of the Xaml parser but the placing the text as content is more natural especially if you have a background in HTML.

The fact the many TextBlocks either have simple short chunks of literal text in or are bound.  Would tip the balance IMO to using the `Text` property.  In addition any globalisation that may come along latter may end with those literals being replaced by bindings as well.

Comment: AnthonyWJones is quite right: Localisation is a key factor here. In practice it usually means all fancy multiple value insertion is actually done elsewhere and only a single resulting text value is bound to the Text property. While the example with multiple runs is "ok" for hard-code English, it is not suitable for commercial applications.

Comment: @HiTech: Anthony's point is certainly valid, but I'm calling BS on "not suitable for commercial applications". That depends entirely on whether globalisation is a requirement of said application, which is it often is not.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: *Every* application we develop nowadays should be expected to support localisation. To assume otherwise is a little short-siighted. Should we really be encouraging bad habits (e.g. hard-wiring text) for newbies? Sorry, but unless you have a better reason that *"we don't always need to localise"* I stand by my original comment.

Comment: @HiTech: sorry, but that's ridiculous. I could make the same "just-in-case" argument to justify all manner of wasteful effort. The reason is simple: globalization and localization takes extra effort, so if you know for a fact that the effort is unnecessary, you're wasting your own time and your client's money by supporting it. Of course, you should always make the trade-off clear to your client.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: *Allowing for the possibility of localisation* is not the same as actually implementing it. Back to my original point *If* you use runs, you cannot easily localise those strings. That's all. End of story. No extra time or cost to me or my clients. I have localised many dozens of apps, including legacy app, so you cannot possibly convince me to go back to hard-coding text *anywhere* :)

Comment: "I have localised many dozens of apps". Exactly - and you will have gotten better at with time and practice. I highly doubt you were as efficient the first time you did it as you are now. I understand the difference between globalization and localization. I admit I have not had to do much localization, but I do tend to make stuff "globalizable" where I see no extra effort to do so. To me though, sticking some text directly inside a TextBlock is quicker and easier than "doing it elsewhere". We may have to agree to differ on this one :)